# Confusion in irreducible, closed subsets of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am reading Görtz and Wedhorn's "Algebraic Geometry I: Schemes with Examples and Exercises". In Proposition 3.23, it is proven that there is a bijection between points of the scheme and closed irreducible subsets. In one moment in the proof, it goes:

"Let $Z$ be an irreducible closed subset. Let $U$ be an affine open subset such that $Z\cap U \neq \emptyset$. Then the closure of $Z \cap U$ is Z, because Z is irreducible."

I tried proving that last line, and I got to a strange result. I thought $Z = \overline{Z \cap U} \cup (Z\cap U^c)$. But this implies that $Z \cap U^c = \emptyset$, which looks strange to me.

Comment: No it doesn't. Consider $Z = V(y) \subset \mathbb A^2$ and $U = D(x)$. Then $Z \cap U$ is the $x$-axis with the origin deleted (in particular the origin lies in $U^c$). So $\overline{Z \cap U} = Z$ and $(Z \cap U^c)$ both contain the origin (since $U^c  = V(x)$ the latter in fact *is* just the origin).

Comment: But $Z = \overline{Z \cap U} \cup (Z \cap U^c)$ implies that one of the sets in the union must be empty, right? Because $Z$ is irreducible. I can't see what is the problem in this reasoning.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it.

Comment: No: irreducibility of $Z$ means that if $Z=A \cup B$ with $A,B$ closed then $A=Z$ or $B=Z$. Both $A$ and $B$ can be nonempty!